# Fixed placeholder bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for the best way to do (with bootstrap) this kind of placeholder. you can write at right part of the placeholder, meanwhile the placeholder holds the text.

I want something like: 
[image]

With bootstrap, you can do it with:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">Text</div>
   <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="text" value="text" placeholder="Additional Info">
</div>
```

With the result:

[image]

Does someone know how to do it? I guess the best option is css styling, but maybe is there a plugin or something any quick way.

Comment: You say you want to do it with Bootstrap, and then you show how to do it with Bootstrap; what part of your problem isn't being met, what do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. If I have to avoid bootstrap, I can handle it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the small text right under the input, you can use an horizontal form. Make sure your viewport is **wider than 768px** otherwise the input is going to show up under the label.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Text</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="name"  class="form-control" type="text" 
             placeholder="Additional Info">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```